# Парсинг сайта с динамическими данными

Tags: парсер, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Подскажите пожалуйста по такому весьма не простому вопросу:

-есть сайт, на нем к примеру есть котировки доллара

-данные постоянно обновляются в онлайне, то есть на странице постоянно обновляется цена доллара

-Так же на сайте есть график - с ценами доллара, но за поздние периоды - дни или часы.

Мне нужно получить эти данные: и те данные, которые постоянно обновляются и те, по которым строится график.

Теоретически у меня есть:

-все заголовки, и тела запросов, которые делает хром(CEF) на сервер

-есть все заголовки ответов на эти запросы, а так же сам полученный ресурс на этот запрос - картинка или текст или .css-файл или скрипт.

-и так же есть обновленная html-страница, которая обновляется после каждого ответа.

У меня это все есть, но я ничего не могу с этим сделать, я не могу понять в какой файл или в каком запросе сервер пересылает постоянно обновляющиеся цены, и так же не могу найти данные на основе которых браузер строит график.

Я понимаю вопрос очень абстрактный, но может кто нибудь может - какие нибудь общие советы по данному вопросу дать ? Инструмент разработчика Хром я так же пробовал, так так же не понятно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135310/discussion-on-question-by-staxcelrom-----).